# Creating color ramp based on quantitative range

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, color, color-ramp

I have a set of polygons with correlation values. I would like to color each polygon based how strong their correlation value is where `0`=*lightest* and `1`=*darkest*.

This means if I have a set of three polygons whose correlation values are: `0.4`, `0.41`, `0.42`, then their colors should be relatively similar. However, when I set the layer symbology to a graduated color ramp, ArcMap splits these values into their own class where `0.4`=*light*, `0.41`=*medium*, `0.42`=*dark*.

In other words, how would I create a color gradient for values based on a range rather than distinct classes?

Answer (score 1):

ArcMap chooses the values based on what is in the data. You can, however, edit these values yourself. In the Symbology tab of your layer, under Quantities, select Graduated colors. Then, under classification, you can choose the number of classes. You can also click the Classify button and choose manual in the classification method. Under Break Values, you can add or remove values.

You can also change the number of classes and edit the range of values.
[image]

In this case, I've changed the number of classes to 3 and edited the values manually. I've also modified the labels to suit my needs.

[image]

Comment: It is interesting that I can manually change the colors, but how would I let Arcmap automatically determine the polygon color based on a range rather than distinct classes? For example, 0.41 must be to some degree darker than 0.4 and 0.422 must be proportionally darker than 0.41.